# mrjob: Is it possible to run a job flow in a VPC?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc, mrjob

I'm using mrjob to run some MapReduce tasks on EMR, and I want to run a job flow in a VPC. I looked at the documentation of mrjob and boto, and none of them seems to support this.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 6):

Right now (v 0.3.5) is not possible. I made a pull request on the github project to add support for the 'api_params' parameter of boto, so you can pass parameters directly to the AWS API, and use the 'Instances.Ec2SubnetId' parameter to run a job flow in a VPC subnet.

Comment: Even with this really usefull parameter (thanks a lot to you), the spot instance does not come up and running. The JobFlow indeed references the subnet, but the master isn't bootstraping. I end up with a bunch of spot requests for the same JobFlow. Termination the JobFlow cancels the queries. Any advice?